# Fuelphp with OAuth2 php server library

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, fuelphp

I'm trying to implement Oauth2 server library into my fuelphp api. I've been following this [tutorial](http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/developing-an-oauth2-authorization-server/) and [this one](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/).

I understood and was able to complete the 2nd tutorial, but that doesn't deal with integrating OAuth into Fuelphp.

What I'm wondering, is how to integrate OAuth2 into my api, I just want to replicated a login? Has anyone any other tutorials on how to do this?

Where in my fuelphp directories do I put the Server/ token/ authorization code?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FuelPHP uses [OPauth](http://opauth.org/) under the hood and it's use is documented in the official [Fuel docs](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/auth/opauth/intro.html)

The server tokens, authorization codes, etc are stored in the `opauth.php` config file.